# Gettiing error in test class

Tags: unit-test

```
@isTest
public class testBilDrugExcutiondetail
{
  static testmethod void testDrugExcutiondetail()
  {



  Account a=new Account();
  a.Name='sid';
  insert a;


Order o = new Order(name='Test1', EffectiveDate=system.today(), AccountId=a.id, status='RFP Creation');
 insert o;

 OrderItem oi = new OrderItem(OrderId=o.id,PricebookEntryId='test');
            insert oi;


 system.assertequals('RFP Creation',o.status);
 PageReference pageRef = Page.Bilcare_Drugs_Execution_Details;
  Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
 ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(o);
    Bilcare_Drugs_Execution_Details d1= new Bilcare_Drugs_Execution_Details(sc);
    d1.Saveaction();

 }
```

Comment: i am getting error like  System.StringException: Invalid id: test

Answer (score 1):

While inserting `OrderItem`, `PricebookEntryId` is expecting an id value. Replace test string with PricebookEntry record id. So you need to insert PricebookEntry record.

```
Product2 prod = new Product2(Name = 'Test Product', 
                     Family = 'Test');
insert prod;

Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();

PricebookEntry standardPrice = new PricebookEntry(
                      Pricebook2Id = pricebookId, Product2Id = prod.Id,
                      UnitPrice = 100, 
                      IsActive = true);
insert standardPrice;


OrderItem oi = new OrderItem(OrderId=o.id,PricebookEntryId=standardPrice.Id);
            insert oi;
```

Comment: Hi Reshma, I have tried this but now i am getting error like System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, AutoPopulatePricebookEntry: execution of AfterInsert

caused by: System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Trigger.AutoPopulatePricebookEntry: line 3, column 1: []

Comment: AutoPopulatePricebookEntry trigger is causing the issue. What is there in that?

Comment: we set the  default standard price by using trigger.

Comment: This would be a different question

Comment: trigger AutoPopulatePricebookEntry on Product2 (after insert) {

sObject s = [select ID from Pricebook2 where IsStandard = TRUE];

for (Product2 newProduct: Trigger.new) {

PricebookEntry z = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2Id=s.ID,Product2Id=newProduct.ID, UnitPrice=0.00, IsActive=TRUE, UseStandardPrice=FALSE);
insert z;

}

}

Comment: This is the trigger which is creating problem.

Comment: The exception is because of you are not getting any record in your SOQL query

Comment: Please post this as a new question as it is not belongs to the current quetion context.

Comment: i am new in salesforce. can you provide me code?

Comment: Refer this link https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000159853&language=en_US

Comment: List<Pricebook2 > pricebook  = [select ID from Pricebook2 where IsStandard = TRUE];
if (pricebook.size() > 0){
 //Your code
}

Comment: i have tried but getting only 17% code coverage.

Comment: You cannot ask all these questions in one thread. If you need us to help then post as a new question with code.